# Как переводится Deep stacking networks на русский?

Tags: нейронные-сети

Пишу курсовой с англоязычного источника. Не могу найти общепринятый и корректный перевод Deep stacking networks. Кто работает с нейросетями, подскажите, пожалуйста, что оно такое и как звучит на русском)

Comment: Не работаю, всего лишь предположение: учитывая, что [deep stacking networks является переименованным deep convex network](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/HutchinsonDengYu-PAMI-2013.pdf), которая в свою очередь основана на `сonvex minimization` и `convex function`. То это по идее должна быть "глубокая выпуклая сеть" до переименовывания (или на надмозговском теперь "глубоко укладывающаяся сеть").